# React Native Realm: if trying to delete parent object that has reference to child, an error should occur

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I have a Realm object, which is a parent to another child objects. The parent holds relationship reference to children. When I try to delete parent object, it gets deleted without throwing any error and child elements are still there. However, I want to have a behaviour such that parent object that contains children cannot be deleted unless the children are deleted.

There is embedded objects solution ( https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/relationships-and-embedded-objects/#embedded-objects ). While child objects do belong to parent and should not exist without it, I do want them to have primary keys which embedded object does not allow to have. The reason is because I want to be able to access the child objects through primary keys without going through chain of relationships. E.g I can have such relation: parent -> child1 -> child2 -> child3. If I use embedded object, then to retrieve child3, I have to go through whole chain. With primary key I can access the required object directly.

The question is: is there some kind of configuration which would overwrite default " allow deletion of parent object no matter if it has children or not " with " allow deletion only if parent contains no reference to children "? Similarly to what relational DB does with foreign keys. **If this is not possible**, then is there a way to access deeply nested child without going through whole chain?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior being described is how Realm works, and by design.

There is nothing to prevent an object *related* to another object from being deleted. Realm objects are separate objects and their life cycle does not depend on other objects. Also, in a Realm object graph there are no parent and child objects, just related objects, with an EmbeddedObject being an exception... but...

An embedded object is different as it's not an object when stored; it's actually part of the parents object graph so when parent is deleted, so is the embedded object. That's why embedded objects don't have their own keys; they are not independently managed objects.

What you're asking about sounds like a cascade delete - where deleting a one object would delete related objects (ones that are in a List for example). That in itself gets tricky as *many to many relationships* are part of Realm; what if deleting an object deletes it's related objects but those are actually related to another object? That gets messy.

One strategy is to use Embedded objects. However, as mentioned in the question, this parent -> child1 -> child2 -> child3 can be challenging but I would question if there would be a better way to build that graph.

The technique we use is to simply ask the object if it's 'children' e.g. related objects, have any other relationships and if not, delete the 'parent' and 'child' objects. We leverage inverse relationships through [LinkingObjects](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/relationships-and-embedded-objects/#find-linking-objects-in-code)

Some pseudo code

```
ParentObject {
   childList: a list of related objects

   function isOkToDelete -> Bool {
      iterate over each child in the list and see if it has an inverse relationship
      if none do, return true as it's ok to delete
   }
}

ChildObject {
   parentObjects: a reference to the parent object(s), LinkingObjects
}
```

within the ChildObject the parentObjects property would be type of LinkingObjects. Realm fully supports many to many relationships so that property could have inverse relationships with 0 or more parent objects.

If parentObjects.count = 1 though, then it's only related to that ParentObject and it's ok to be deleted.

If all of the child objects only have one parent, you can then programatically implement a cascade delete, deleting each child and then the parent.